# Understanding appendChild In JS in relation to the use of `this`

Tags: javascript, appendchild, child-nodes

I'm having trouble understanding how to append created elements, so they are held within other created elements. If my explanation of this is confusing please let me know I'll try to clarify.

***Context / Goal***

The goal or context of this snippet is to create and track a character counter that dynamically adjusts in the users browser. The twist is; I needed it to apply to every `<textarea></textarea>` that may be on the page.

To help bring the users attention to the character counter, I wanted create a span to wrap around just the count i.e. 255. and adjust the color of the font dynamically when certain paramiters are met.

**What I have currently**

```
<div></div>
```

**What I'm after**

```
<div>
   <span id="cid0"></span>
</div>
```

**My JS** - **(See full script here - *[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grhLupp7/77/)*)**

```
  // create wrapper & span element
  this.wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  this.span = document.createElement("span");
  this.span.id = "cid" +i;
  this.span.appendChild(this.wrapper);

  this.wrapper.innerHTML = 'Chars left: ';
  this.span.innerHTML = (this.MAX - input.value.length);
```

If anyone could clarify how to achieve what I am after, where I'm going wrong and if I have made a made a mistake I would be greatful for the assistance.

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: @Rayon The span is non existant. I only see `<div></div>` created when I test the snippet.

Comment: `this.wrapper.innerHTML` will remove the `span`

Comment: @Rayon I don't follow please clarify.

Comment: `.innerHTML` will remove all content of the box to fill with the new HTML, in this case `Chars left:`. So you are removing the `<span>` with `this.wrapper.innerHTML`

Comment: However, `this.wrapper` is not appended in nowhere, so isn't in DOM tree

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I see, but if this is the case how do I preserve the span whilst till passing new `.innerHTML` to `this.wrapper?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude does append work similarly to css positioning? I.e static, relative, absolute. etc. For examlple does the parent have to be appended for the child to append correctly?

Comment: You need to modify the `nodeText`  instead of the whole `innerHTML`, or add a new tag that will be sibling of that `<span id="cidXX">`

Comment: Above all: With `this.span.appendChild` you are appending the wrapper div element as a child to the span element. I think you wanted to achieve the exact opposite, correct?

Comment: Append have nothing related with css positioning. Append will attach an element in the DOM tree, no more, in the position that you need.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I was more refering to the relation of the elements when using css positioning rather than actual positioning on a page.

Comment: CSS positioning have nothing related with JS append. I can't imagine in what way are you thinking in append elements.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude When you position a absolute div you usually need to make sure its parent is relative do you not? There for there is a child parent relation between the two elements. The child can't be set properly without the parent being set.

Comment: Yeah, but appending elements is not this way. You can append an element to another element that is not in the DOM yet. It works internally in memory so when you append the top parent element you will append with all properties and inner elements that you play in memory. CSS positioning works as you said with relative / absolute, but not with static / fixed. So it's not comparisable, since languages are different and for different purposes, in CSS you don't append anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted to achieve

```
<div>
   Chars left: <span id="cid0">xxxxx</span>
</div>
```

Right? Then try this

```
  // create wrapper & span element
  this.wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  this.wrapper.innerHTML = 'Chars left: ';
  this.span = document.createElement("span");
  this.span.id = "cid" +i;
  this.span.innerHTML = (this.MAX - input.value.length);

  this.wrapper.appendChild(this.span);
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Thank you! It appears I had, Line 8 in your example the wrong way around, as well as a few other structural issues. Much appreciated good sire!